# Problems with css inside a directory

Tags: css, directory

I have a problem where I want to redirect to a css file which stylesheet link is inside essentials.php in the main directory. however when including the essentials.php the browser redirects to the wrong url see image. how can i fix this?

[image: Redirectproblem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue with a php variable $site which is defined as the url, in this way i can change the variable from localhost to the real site and is it easy to switch. In this way I do not have directory problems since the whole url is given.

```
$siteurl=localhost/project

href="<?php echo "$siteurl";?>/videos/watch?v=">
```